# How do I correctly initialize a function which interacts with the redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Let's say I have the following function which returns a filepath from the state, based on the filename (as input parameter) and if it doesn't exist returns an URL from a server.

```
const getFilepath = (state: IRootState) => (url: string) => {
    const file = getFilenameByURL(state, url);
    return file ? file : getRemoteFilePath(url);
}
```

Now I have a component `FileBrowser`, which has a list of file names. Here, I want to initialize this function. Currently I'd do it like this:

```
const { getFilepathByFilename } = useSelector((state: IRootState) => ({ getFilepathByFilename: getFilepath(state)}))
```

Now when I want to access the path from an element in the list, I do it like this:

```
const filePath = getFilepathByFilename(fileName)
```

Now this seems to work, but I run into an infinite rerender loop because the `getFilepath` function in the `FileBrowser` gets set over and over again.

I feel like I'm implementing a wrong pattern here. How would I go about creating a function which accesses the state, but doesn't cause infinite rerenders? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use useCallback for function getFilepath. This way you can persist you function and create it only once. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To persist function reference across rerender of component you can use useCallback, like this:

```
const getFilepath = useCallback ((state: IRootState) => (url: string) => {
    const file = getFilenameByURL(state, url);
    return file ? file : getRemoteFilePath(url);
}, [])
```

Comment: nit pick, this function can be reduced to this: `... => getFilenameByURL(state, url) || getRemoteFilePath(url)`